# If a poset is Dedekind-complete, is its opposite necessarily Dedekind-complete?

Tags: order-theory

Call a poset $X$ Dedekind-complete iff for all **non-empty** sets $A \subseteq X$, the following are equivalent.

1. $A$ has an upper bound
2. $A$ has a **least** upper bound.

Supposing $X = (X, \leq)$ is Dedekind-complete, is $X^\mathrm{op} = (X,\geq)$ necessarily Dedekind complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the infimum can be characterized as the supremum of the lower bounds, and conversely.